# Is there some quick magic trick to remove digital signature form field from pdf file just by editing PDF in text editor?

Tags: pdf, edit, digital-signature, scripting-language

What I want is to edit PDF file, and remove digital signature form field. I would like to do that without buying Adobre Pro liscence. I remember some time ago I opened PDF file in text editor and saw some scripting language, so I am wondering if I can edit PDF file directly in text editor, remove the proper lines from PDF, save and that's it!
My question:
  - Is that possible?
  - Are there any document checksums, or some existing number of objects per page in PDF file?
  - If yes, so what should I look for, and what should I change?

Comment: You might be able to in a Hex editor, like HxD, but you would want to zero bytes. You can't safely "move" anything, since PDF files use actual bye offsets to find objects. As for what to zero out, to remove just the signature, and not prevent viewing of the file, is difficult. Objects can be compressed, so they would not show up in the binary stream, but I don't imagine this would be the case for a digital signature. You can find the PDF standard online, and from there you can find the keys you want, and from that what entries to zero out.

Comment: Yeah, I was exploring that document, not so thoroughly, and tried to remove some objects with something like /Ft Sig, but every time, I do that, it was corrupted when I was opening. Ok, so it seems, I will need to go deeper for that

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer** If you choose to edit or remove signatures from a PDF, be aware that you're doing so at your own risk. This action can have legal implications. It's advisable to seek professional guidance before proceeding.

## How to remove digital signature from PDF

1. Open the PDF in Google Chrome
2. Click "Print" icon in the top right corner
3. For "Destination" select "Save as PDF"

## How to verify digital signatures have been removed

You can use the command line tool `pdfsig`:

`pdfsig my-document.pdf`

The output should include this sentence:

```
File 'my-document.pdf' does not contain any signatures
```